# Multiple Response Body Examples depending on media type in OpenApi 3.0.0/Swagger

Tags: api, swagger, documentation, openapi

I am trying to document the response for an endpoint that accepts multiple mime type requests and returns a different response based on the type. One response type, pdf, returns its own schema separate from the others. The rest all return the same schema and same example. This syntax works. Almost. Except in the UI example, the JSON response is also showing the string "$ref: example-two.json" along with the appropriate response example. Like:

```
{
  "key": "value",
  "key2": "value2",
  "$$ref: example-two.json"
}
```

when it should just be:

```
{
  "key": "value",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

I've been scouring the docs and stack and google and I don't see any examples of making something like this work. Or rather, I'm not seeing why this one isn't working, but I haven't seen any examples that include $refs for each example.

```
responses:
    200:
        content:
            application/pdf:
                schema:
                    $ref: ../app.yaml#/components/schemas/ModelOne
            application/json:
                schema:
                    $ref: ../app.yaml#/components/schemas/ModelTwo
                examples:
                    Example:
                        value:
                            $ref: example-two.json
            text/html:
                schema:
                    $ref: ../app.yaml#/components/schemas/ModelTwo
                examples:
                    Example:
                        value:
                            $ref: example-two.json
```

For context - I cannot change the endpoint behavior and I do need to show an example for each mime type even if they are the same. Because the one is different. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to `$ref` an example in OpenAPI 3.0:

1) Define the example in the `components/examples` section. In this case the `$ref` is used inside the `examples.<name>` key (not inside `value`).

```yaml
                examples:
                    Example:
                        $ref: '#/components/examples/MyExample'
                ...

components:
  examples:
    MyExample:
      summary: Optional short description of this example
      value:
        key: value
        key2: value2
```

2) If the `example-two.json` file contains just the example value (in this case - sample JSON), you can use `externalValue` to link to that file:

```yaml
                examples:
                    Example:
                        externalValue: example-two.json
```

Notes:

- Relative URLs in `externalValue` are resolved against the API server URL (`servers[*].url`) and not the location of the OpenAPI definition file. You may need to use an absolute URL.
- Examples with `externalValue` are currently (as of December 2019) not displayed in Swagger UI - see [issue #5433](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5433).

Comment: Thanks for the response! When I try it without the value: key after Example, your first example, nothing shows at all, unfortunately. I can't use the second example as I need it to display in the UI.

Comment: What version of Swagger UI do you use? Open the browser dev tools > Console tab and evaluate `versions`.

Comment: Did you use my 1st example as is, or did you try to `$ref` an external file there? If the latter, what's the contents of the external file?

Comment: ya, I had to try the $ref, the $ref is a local json file with the expected json output. And I'm on Swagger UI "version":"3.23.6"

Comment: _"$ref is a local json file with the expected json output."_ That's the problem. The external JSON file must be in the format of the OAS3 [Example Object](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#exampleObject), i.e. `{"summary": "Optional short description of this example", "value": {"key": "value", "key2": "value2"}}`.